# Serialização dos models no Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa, serialização

Em alguns códigos, percebi que é utilizada a interface serializable nas classes de modelo, enquanto em outros não. Entendo que a interface serializable serve para persistir um objeto em seu estado atual ou transmiti-lo pela rede. Visto que no Spring terá um banco de dados para fazer esta persistência, qual seria a utilização dessa interface ? sempre devo usá-la ou apenas em casos específicos ? Se apenas em casos específicos, quais seriam estes ?

Answer (score -2):

Se sua classe implementa Serializable, os objetos dessa classe podem ser transformados em um stream de bytes e armazenados em um arquivo por exemplo, ou enviados pela rede, como você mesmo mencionou. Isso geralmente acontece usando a classes na hierarquia de InputStream e OutputStream.
Escrever um programa que instancia um objeto e o salva em um arquivo, outro que lê esse arquivo e recupera o objeto vai te ajudar a entender o conceito. Um segundo exercício pode ser enviar o objeto via socket.

Já o processo de persistir o objeto em um banco de dados é diferente. Geralmente os frameworks mapeiam os campos do objeto para uma instrução SQL que guarda os valores no banco, um processo totalmente diferente, que não faz o uso da interface Serializable e a hierarquia de classes que usam a interface.